# How can I setup an Apollo client in React for both upload and subscriptions?

Tags: reactjs, file-upload, react-apollo, apollo-client, graphql-subscriptions

I would like to set up a graphql client with React for both uploading file and handle subscriptions from a graphql server. 
The file upload and the other queries work well. The problem is with subscriptions. I get in the browser console the following error: 
`WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:3001/subscriptions' failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response`

I have used `apollo-upload-client` for file upload and `apollo-link-ws` for subscriptions.

I can see that  [subscriptions-transport-ws](https://github.com/apollographql/subscriptions-transport-ws%22subscriptions-transport-ws%22) suggests using `createNetworkInterface` and `addGraphQLSubscriptions` but this approach is not compatible with `apollo-upload-client` that only supports `createUploadLink`.

I'm stuck. Please help.

I setup my client like this:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ApolloClient from 'apollo-client';
import { ApolloProvider } from 'react-apollo';
import { createUploadLink } from 'apollo-upload-client';
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';
import { ApolloLink, Observable, split } from 'apollo-link';
import { WebSocketLink } from 'apollo-link-ws';
import { getMainDefinition } from 'apollo-utilities';


const cache = new InMemoryCache();

const request = async (operation) => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    operation.setContext({
        headers: {
            authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : '',
        },
    });
};

const httpLink = createUploadLink({ uri: 'http://localhost:3001/graphql' });

// Create a WebSocket link:
const wsLink = new WebSocketLink({
    uri: 'ws://localhost:3001/subscriptions',
    options: {
        reconnect: true
    },
});

// using the ability to split links, you can send data to each link
// depending on what kind of operation is being sent
const link = split(
    // split based on operation type
    ({ query }) => {
        const { kind, operation } = getMainDefinition(query);
        return kind === 'OperationDefinition' && operation === 'subscription';
    },
    wsLink,
    httpLink,
);


const requestLink = new ApolloLink((operation, forward) =>
    new Observable((observer) => {
        let handle;
        Promise.resolve(operation)
            .then(oper => request(oper))
            .then(() => {
                handle = forward(operation).subscribe({
                    next: observer.next.bind(observer),
                    error: observer.error.bind(observer),
                    complete: observer.complete.bind(observer),
                });
            })
            .catch(observer.error.bind(observer));

        return () => {
            if (handle) handle.unsubscribe();
        };
    }));

const apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
    link: ApolloLink.from([
        requestLink,
        link,
    ]),
    cache,
});

export const withApolloClient = App => (
    <ApolloProvider client={apolloClient}>
        <App client={apolloClient} />
    </ApolloProvider>
);

export default apolloClient;
```

Comment: What kind of server implementation are you using to support GraphQL subscriptions?

Comment: your backend is nodejs or something different?

Comment: Server was made with nodejs using the modules `apollo-server-express`, `apollo-upload-server`, `express`, `graphql` and `subscriptions-transport-ws`

Comment: I tried to think of the problem. but Its hard to guess and answer. Any chance you can share source code? I would like to experiment with it. I might get some better idea and solution to it.

Comment: did you figure it out? @FedericoBellucci

Comment: Hi Victor. No, I didn't. But I'm not interested anymore

Answer (score 0):

I am using a similar config but instead of importing `WebSocketLink` from `apollo-link-ws` I imported it from `@apollo/client`.

With that setup i had both the subscription and upload working.

`import { WebSocketLink } from "@apollo/client/link/ws";`

Answer (score 0):

Use the `uploadLink` created via `createUploadLink` in the `split`:

```
const uploadLink = createUploadLink({
  uri: 'http://localhost:3001/graphql',
});

const link = split(
    // split based on operation type
    ({ query }) => {
        const { kind, operation } = getMainDefinition(query);
        return kind === 'OperationDefinition' && operation === 'subscription';
    },
    wsLink,
    uploadLink,
);
```

**Explanation**: The `uploadLink` already checks whether the GraphQL query contains a file upload. If not, it will do a normal fetch.

See [the apollo-upload-client docs](https://github.com/jaydenseric/apollo-upload-client#function-createuploadlink):

> Creates a terminating Apollo Link for Apollo Client that fetches a GraphQL multipart request if the GraphQL variables contain files (by default FileList, File, Blob, or ReactNativeFile instances), or else fetches a regular GraphQL POST or GET request (depending on the config and GraphQL operation).

Answer (score -2):

I would suggest to use graphql-server-express like [this](https://github.com/logisticinfotech/nodejs-graphql-subscription-reactjs-demo/blob/master/express/server.js)